# How to get all the models (one for each set of parameters) using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search

From my understanding:

`best_estimator_` provides the estimator with highest score; `best_score_` provides the score of the selected estimator; `cv_results_` may be exploited to get the scores of all estimators.

However, it is not clear to me how to get the estimators themselves.

Comment: `GridSearchCV` already has the best estimator fitted, assuming you kept `refit=True`. You can simply use `my_estimator = clf.best_estimator_`, then predict with `my_estimator.predict(X)`. Alternatively, you could also predict with `clf.predict(X)`. However, if you want the other estimators, then you'll have to iterate through your param grid with the estimator object you used and fit on your training data.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, you cannot. But what you can do is taking the best parameter combination from `best_params_` and fit the model again with those same parameters. 
Check out attributes of [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)