# Can you get all estimators from an sklearn grid search (GridSearchCV)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I recently tested many hyperparameter combinations using `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`. I want to know if there is a way to call all previous estimators that were trained in the process.

```py
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=my_estimator, param_grid=parameters)
# `my_estimator` is a gradient boosting classifier object
# `parameters` is a dictionary containing all the hyperparameters I want to try
```

I know I can call the best estimator with `search.best_estimator_`, but I would like to call all other estimators as well so I can test their individual performance.

The search took around 35 hours to complete, so I really hope I do not have to do this all over again.

NOTE: This was asked a few years ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774769/how-to-get-all-the-models-one-for-each-set-of-parameters-using-gridsearchcv)), but `sklearn` has been updated multiple times since and the anwer may be different now (I hope).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, none of the tested models are saved, except (optionally, but by default) one final one trained on the entire training set, your `best_estimator_`.  Especially when models store significant amounts of data (e.g. KNNs), saving all the fitted estimators would be very memory-expensive, and usually not of much use.  (`cross_validate` does have a parameter `return_estimator`, but the hyperparameter tuners do not.  If you have a compelling reason to add it, it probably wouldn't take much work and you could open a GitHub Issue at sklearn.)

However, you do have the `cv_results_` attribute that documents the scores of all of the tested estimators.  That's usually enough for inspection purposes.