# Is there a way to get all computed coefficients in a GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, lasso-regression

I am trying different ML models, all using a pipeline which includes a transformer and an algorithm, 'nested' in a GridSearchCV to find the best hyperparameters.

When running Ridge, Lasso and ElasticNet regressions, I would like to store all the computed coefficients, not only the `best_estimator_` coefficients, in order to plot them according to the `alpha`'s path.
In other words, when the GridSearchCV changes the `alpha` parameter and fit a new model, I would like to store the resulting coefficients, to plot them against the `alpha` values.

You can take a look at [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ridge_path.html) official scikit post for a beautiful example.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
import time
start = time.time()

# Cross-validated - Ridge Regression
model_ridge = make_pipeline(transformer, Ridge()) # my transformer is already defined 

alphas = np.logspace(-5, 5, num = 50)
params = {'ridge__alpha' : alphas}
    
grid = GridSearchCV(model_ridge, param_grid = params, cv=10)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
regressor = grid.estimator.named_steps['ridge'].coef_ # when I add this line, it returns an error
    
stop = time.time()
training_time = stop-start

y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)

Ridge_Regression_results = {'Algorithm' : 'Ridge Regression', 
                             'R²' : grid.score(X_train, y_train), 
                             'MAE' : mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred), 
                             'RMSE' : np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)),
                             'Training time (sec)' : training_time}
```

In this topic: [return coefficients from Pipeline object in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856280/return-coefficients-from-pipeline-object-in-sklearn), the author was adviced to use the `named_steps` attribute of the pipeline.
But in my case, when I try to use it, it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18260/3310195105.py in <module>
     13 
     14 grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
---> 15 regressor = grid.estimator.named_steps['ridge'].coef_
     16 
     17 

AttributeError: 'Ridge' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

For this to work, my guess is that this storing should happen during the GridSearchCV *loop*, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359261/can-you-get-all-estimators-from-an-sklearn-grid-search-gridsearchcv might help. Long story short, there's no way you can get them with hyperparameter tuners like `GridSearchCV` as they do not store all the fitted estimators.

Comment: Alrigth then, thank's for the very efficient still sad answer ahah.

Comment: The error you're seeing is because `grid.estimator` is the unfitted input pipeline.  You can use `grid.best_estimator_.named_steps` to get the final refitted best-hyperparameter object, but that doesn't answer your main question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the coefficients by making them "scores," although it isn't very semantically correct.

```py
import pandas as pd

def myscores(estimator, X, y):
    r2 = estimator.score(X, y)
    coefs = estimator.named_steps["ridge"].coef_ 
    ret_dict = {
        f'a_{i}': coef for i, coef in enumerate(coefs)
    }
    ret_dict['r2'] = r2
    return ret_dict

grid = GridSearchCV(
    model_ridge,
    param_grid=params,
    scoring=myscores,
    refit='r2'
)

print(pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)
```